# How can I run a light (SPV) node on Linux?

Tags: nodes, spv

I tried to sync the blockchain and, though I have ample free disk space (>500 GB on my computer, the chain is ~265) I've been having a hard time. So, how can I use an SPV node to send transactions and/or view the blockchain?

NOTE: don't do this if you don't have to because the blockchain needs nodes to ensure adequate distribution.

Comment: related: https://btcinformation.org/en/choose-your-wallet

Answer (score 2):

Try Electrum. Exact details on how to install depend on Linux distribution used.

Also Wasabi Wallet could be good choice, easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Since your constraint is the blockchain size, it seems you would be fine with running bitcoind with `--prune` enabled to something like 2gb or similar. This is technically not an SPV solution, but you would have access to the bitcoin-qt gui ( if that's the version of bitcoind you have installed ) and you'd be able to run with your minimal constraints.